# PDF file size decreases significantly after removing 1 field

Tags: pdf, adobe, filesize, acrobat

Using: Adobe Acrobat XI Pro, Windows 7 Enterprise SP1

A PDF file I'm maintaining is currently 1112 KB in size. But after I remove a duplicate text field and save the file, the file size decreases significantly to 300 KB.

Have anyone ever seen this happen after changing a PDF file ? I’m concerned that the JavaScript code I entered for other (calculated) fields may have been removed somehow.

Comment: Please share the file for analysis.

Comment: As it's possible for a PDF file to contain a lot of junk, and as Adobe Acrobat is pretty good at saving PDF files, I wouldn't be overly worried. Also, think about how much Javascript you would need to fill 800 KB... But as mkl says, it's impossible to say anything definitive about this without having the PDF file.

Comment: What happens when you do a Save as… before removing the field? It is likely that the document has been simply saved before, which, because PDF is incrementally saved, will always increase its size. Save as… does reorganize the document, and thus reduce the file size.